# How to limit get access for owners only in firebase storage?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I'm testing new Firebase Storage local Emulator. For my rules, it gives me the following error:

> com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.common.EvaluationException: Error: {path/to/my/file/storage.rules} line [5], column [21]. Null value error.

The rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /item/{id}/file.txt {
      allow get: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == resource.metadata.owner; // Error line 5
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == resource.metadata.owner;
      // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 100MB
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == request.resource.metadata.owner
        && request.resource.size < 100 * 1024 * 1024;
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like the rules for GET are invalid. Maybe it's because of the resource.metadata.owner that doesn't exist? If it's true, then how can I limit the access for owners of the file only?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try to check if the metadata itself exists before comparing it

```
allow get: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.metadata.owner != null && resource.metadata.owner == request.auth.uid;
```

If you find any future issues, test it in a deployed project as it may just be a fault in the emulator

Source:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#custom-claim_attributes_and_roles
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#request_methods

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it does not represent the appropriate CRUD operation within storage"?

Comment: those links relate to firestore rules, and we dont seem to have the same access to the database from the storage rules